# Convertir objeto en string separado

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo separo el siguiente valor?

```js
Wed Nov 09 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central), Thu Nov 17 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)
```

Previamente lo recibo como objeto y lo paso a string con `toString`. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo separarlos para que queden en variables separadas?

```js
this.m_fecha_inicio = this.m_rango_fechas.split(',')
```

Lo hago de la siguiente manera pero me da el siguiente error:

> type String[] is not asignable  to type string.

Comment: Puedes poner algo más de código, porque me da la impresión que tú tienes un array de fechas (Date), por lo que ya estarían separadas. Y tú al hacer toString() las estas juntando

Comment: A mi me da la impresión de que `this.m_fecha_inicio` esta declarado como tipo `string` y al hacer `this.m_rango_fechas.split(',')` lo convierte en String [] y eso no lo puedes asignar a dicha variable. Agrega más código para ver

Comment: Split devuelve un arreglo. Puedes acceder a un elemento con `[]`. Por ejemplo el primero con `[0]`

Comment: Muchas gracias por comentar y darme su tiempo para responderme amigos :), pero lo soluciones asi -> this.fecha_inicio =this.rango_fechas[0].toString();, ahi publique la respuesta y de antemano muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

lo resolvi de la siguiente manera, perdon que no contestara es que en mi pueblo se va mucho el internet :(

```js
this.fecha = this.rango_fechas[0].toString();
```

el cual obtengo el primer valor de mi array y lo convierto a string asi puedo utilizarlo de manera individual. ya luego uso una funcion aparte para darle formato.